# ¿Cómo usar inner join?

Tags: php, sql

tengo esta consulta

```
    $query=$db->query("select empleado,count(*) as v
                       from empleado 
                       inner join oficinas on 
                       empleado.numero=oficinas.numero");
```

pero me da esta salida [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿alguien me dice que estoy haciendo mal? :3

El caso es el siguiente: tengo una tabla de empleados y otra de oficinas. Hay 7 oficinas registradas (en la tabla de oficinas, con diferentes id por supuesto), y hay 12 empleados que pertenecen a una oficina cada uno.

Varios de ellos pertenecen a la misma oficina. Pero por ejemplo, en la tabla oficina está registrada la oficina 8 pero no hay ningún empleado en la oficina 8, ¿me entienden? Entonces como no hay ningún empleado en la oficina 8, no quiero mostrar ese registro. Quiero mostrar solo los empleados que pertenecen a una oficina. En realidad quiero mostrar cuántos empleados tiene cada oficina, pero las oficinas que tengan empleados pues.

Pero esta consulta no me funcionó. :c Alguien écheme una mano please :)

Comment: Tienes **dos errores** uno leve y otro gravísimo. El error leve es que hay un error en la manera en que obtienes la conexión a la bd o en la manera en que la consultas. Eso es lo de menos, se puede resolver... aunque creo que no has presentado todo el código... no veo donde haces el `fetch()`. **Lo grave es el error grave** que consiste en estar mandando una consulta hecha a la base de datos. Esa práctica es una puerta abierta a la inyección SQL (http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php ), por lo que te sugiero que uses consultas preparadas para enviar tus consultas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en que el query que hiciste esta mal. Nunca lo probaste en la base de datos no??

Voy a tratar de arreglarlo, pero sin mas información se complica:

```
select oficina,count(empleados) as v 
from 
    empleado 
 inner join 
    oficinas on empleado.numero=oficinas.numero
group by oficina
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando la información de tu [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60400/por-qu%C3%A9-esta-consulta-me-devuelve-11-registros), parece que la consulta deseada para obtener la cantidad de empleados por oficina, es:

```
select o.numero, o.ciudad, count(*) as cantidad_empleados
  from oficinas o
  join empleado e
    on e.numero_o = o.numero
 group by o.numero, o.ciudad
```